# Extract fit error from parameter table to use as a variable

Tags: fitting, variable

Is there anyway to extract the fit error and store it in a variable. I have done something similar to use actual fit results as

```
SomeDataFit=NonlinearModelFit[SomeData,m*x+c,{m,c},x]
x = m /. SomeDataFit["BestFitParameters"]
```

is there a similar way to extract the fit error from

```
SomeDataFit["ParameterTable"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen `SomeDataFit["ParameterErrors"]`?

Comment: Are you talking about the residuals or about estimated errors of the fit parameters or something else?

Comment: @march the error in the fit parameter. E.g. the slope, `m` is 123 and the error in `m` from the parameter table is 0.123. I want to store 0.123 in a variable and use it else where.

Comment: @J.M. Perfect, as always! If you submit as an answer I can accept to give credit?

Comment: Altho the doc page for `NonlinearModelFit[]` is a bit long, please do read the "Details and Options" section at the very least, if you're curious about available properties.

Comment: @J.M. I will do. Thanks again!